# Read table then delete and display new

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my first display of the page(actually the data in rows and columns are generated from server code and database). Please also pay attention to the attributes of each data

```
  <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="1" class="decorate">Item3</td>
            <td class="decorate"><p>Description<p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="decorate">Item1</td>
            <td class="decorate"><p>Description1</p><p>Description2</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="2" class="decorate">Item2</td>
            <td class="decorate"><p>Description3<p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
                <div id="tablediv"></div>
```

And here is the js code to read that data on OnLoad event and append the data into "tablediv" after they are sorted.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var arr = new Array();
    $('table tr').each(function() {
        var $row = $(this);
        var key = $row.find('td:first').html();
        var value = $row.find('td:last').html();
        console.log(value);
        arr.push([key, value]);
    });

    arr.sort(function(a, b) {
        var valueA, valueB;
        valueA = a[0]; // sort by the first value of array
        valueB = b[0];
        if (valueA < valueB) {
            return -1;
        }
        else if (valueA > valueB) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    });

    var root=document.getElementById('tablediv');
    var table=document.createElement('table');
    var tbo=document.createElement('tbody');
    var row, cell;
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
    {
        row=document.createElement('tr');
        for(var j=0;j<2;j++)
        {
            cell=document.createElement('td');
            cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(arr[i][j]));
            row.appendChild(cell);
        }
        tbo.appendChild(row);
    }
    table.appendChild(tbo);
    root.appendChild(table);
});
```

However, I don't like to put it in the `tablediv` but to completely replace the previous table (the previous one has no id or class for me to tell where it is in jquery code).

How can I do this ? And that I also would want to retain attributes inside previous table's td. My array use here need more implementation...:-(

Comment: it gets more and more difficult :-D

Comment: If this is the only table on the page (and it looks as though it must be, or other things would probably be breaking when you use the jQuery selector `'table tr'`), then you can select that table with the jQuery selector `'table'`.  You can remove this and replace it, or you can sort in place in this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just sort in place: http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/T44Nn/

```
var $table = $("table")
var rows = $table.find("tr").toArray();
rows.sort(function(a, b) {
    var left = $(a).find("td:first").html(), // .text() ??
        right = $(b).find("td:first").html();
    return left < right ? -1 : left > right ? +1 : 0;
});
$(rows).each(function() {
    $(this).appendTo($table);
});​
```

This should mean that you don't have to copy anything from table to table, just reuse the rows intact.